Graceful shutdown in Go application without console on windows
I have an application written in Go for Windows, and I'm trying to implement graceful shutdown while taking into account the specifics of my application.
The application is launched by another process with the CREATE_NO_WINDOW (0x08000000) flag, meaning it has no console window (nor any other windows).
Currently, I'm using:
signal.Notify(signalChan, []os.Signal{syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGKILL, syscall.SIGTERM}...)


This works if the application has a console window and we close it, but during a Windows shutdown, no signal is received.
Is there a way for the application to detect that the OS is shutting down, especially considering that the application has no windows? may have to use the win api
UPD
For now, i've decided to create a hidden window using the WinAPI and subscribe to its WM_ENDSESSION event.

That was a long time ago I've touched Win32 API but your approach sounds about right to me. Does it also work if you subscribe to WM_QUIT, WM_CLOSE and WM_DESTROY? In theory, it should also cover the case of graceful termination during the logout — as well as some other possible cases of termination.
